# How do I extract the "detail" from square charge

Tags: php, square, square-connect

When I catch the exception from the square charge object, I am returned with `[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"CARD_TOKEN_USED","detail":"Card nonce already used; please request new nonce."}]}`

I want to extract only "detail" to convey to the user.  How do I do this.  I tried `$e->getDetail()` and `$e->getMessage()->getDetail()` and `$e['detail']` and `$e['errors'][0]['detail']` but nothing is working.  How do I do this?  Using php connect library

Comment: you can do something like this:- https://eval.in/728552

Comment: the [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] bit before the json bit breaks it.  I suppose I could regex it out but it seems this should be more straight forward?

Comment: i din't get you

Comment: technically the exception is $exception = '[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"CARD_TOKEN_USED","detail":"Card nonce already used; please request new nonce."}]}';

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I was catching a standard exception but square has a library for that -> if you need the answer:  `catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
echo $e->getResponseBody()->errors[0]->detail;
}`